# Drupal не подгружется css и js

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, http-status-code-500

Залил drupal на хост, открыл стартовую страницу друпала а там такая штука
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
не подгружаются css. Посмотрел в консоль, не может загрузить ни css файлы, ни js, с проблемой 500. Как решать? php 7.2, drupal 8.6.2

Comment: Это похоже на серверную ошибку 
Но лучше пути чекни на всякий если html запустило то и остальное должно прогружать

Comment: просто сбрось кеш сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь права доступа к папкам:

1. sites
2. sites/default
3. sites/default/files

Comment: проставил всем им максимальный доступ, не помогает